# How to know the location on slurm script using the squeue command

Tags: slurm

I am running several experiments on a cluster. I have to use so many scripts from different application folders and its hard to track with slurm scripts are currently running. Is there any way to know the location of the scripts also using squeue command?

I use "squeue - username -all" command to list all the jobs I am running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request the `command` that is run, this will give you the location of the script that was submitted:

```
$ squeue --user $USER --Format jobid,command:100
68286079            /home/users/[...]/exp1/submit.sh
[...]
```